# ssrs run all parameter options

Tags: ssrs-2008

I had developed a report with three different parameters in it for users to log in ad hoc and select what they wanted and run the report.  Adding up all the different combinations of parameter selections and there are 150 different reports.

Now the requirements have changed so that we need all 150 reports done in excel and saved out to the network each month.  How can I schedule all 150 options to run and save in excel (without having 150 subscriptions).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Enterprise Edition? If so, you could create a data-driven subscription. You would need to set up a table that has 150 rows in it, with at least 3 columns representing each parameter. For flexibility, I'd add a column for render format (EXCEL) and for target folder. Then you can create one subscription.

Otherwise, if you have only Standard Edition, your only choice is to create 150 subscriptions. In that case, I'd be inclined to write a script to use with RS.EXE to generate the 150 subscriptions.

Here's a sample script that produces an Excel file. I re-read your post and decided you didn't really need the subscription aspect of this. You just need to render the report, and then to schedule this, just create a batch file for the command line and schedule it with SQL Server Agent.

This code is adapted from the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render(v=sql.100).aspx#Y1258

You type this in using Notepad and then save the file as renderExcel.rss. The file extension is important - don't save it as txt file. Of course, change the file path, parameter names, and values. I just had these to execute on my dev machine and make sure it actually works!

```
Public Sub Main()

  rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

  ' Render arguments
  Dim result As Byte() = Nothing
  Dim reportPath As String = "/Sales/Reseller Sales Cumulative Sales"
  Dim format As String = "EXCEL"
  Dim historyID As String = Nothing
  Dim devInfo As String = Nothing


  ' Prepare report parameter.
  Dim parameters(2) As ParameterValue
  parameters(0) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(0).Name = "SalesTerritoryGroup"
  parameters(0).Value = "Europe"
  parameters(1) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(1).Name = "Year"
  parameters(1).Value = "2007" 
  parameters(2) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(2).Name = "Quarter"
  parameters(2).Value = "1"

  Dim credentials As DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
  Dim showHideToggle As String = Nothing
  Dim encoding As String
  Dim mimeType As String
  Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
  Dim reportHistoryParameters As ParameterValue() = Nothing
  Dim streamIDs As String() = Nothing

  Dim execInfo As New ExecutionInfo
    Dim execHeader As New ExecutionHeader()
    Dim SessionId As String
    Dim extension As String = ""

  rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader

    execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID)

    rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us")

    SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID
    Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID)


  Try
     result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, extension, _
           encoding, mimeType, warnings, streamIDs)


  Catch e As SoapException
     Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml)
  End Try
  ' Write the contents of the report to an Excel file.
  Try
     Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create("myReport.xls", result.Length)
     Console.WriteLine("File created.")
     stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length)
     Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.")
     stream.Close()
  Catch e As Exception
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
  End Try
 End Sub
```

To execute it, you need to run this at the command line:

```
rs -i renderExcel.rss -s http://localhost/reportserver -e Exec2005
```

This code only creates one file. You need to add a way to loop through it to set your parameters for each parameter combination and then render.

Comment: Thank you Stacia.  I don't have enterprise edition.  Could you do a sample script for me that renders a report to excel selecting a specific parameter?

Comment: I can - but it's going to be a few days. I'm under the gun on a project right now.

Comment: Sure, no problem I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Thank you Stacia, my apologies for responding late.  So where do I save the .rss file to?  The webserver somewhere? If so can you talk me through that.  When I save to the local network it saves it as renerExcel.rss.txt.  Or am I missing an application or something that would recognize a .rss file.     Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Oh, and when I save the file I am choosing "All file types" but it still forces the .txt on the end?

Comment: Sorry for the panic, I had to change a windows setting and uncheck "Hide extensions of known file types" and that seemed to do the trick.  I may have more questions on the script but at least I can find it from the cmd line now.:)

Comment: Ok, the code is working great for reports that have SQL Server as the data source.  However my three parameter report has Analysis Services Cube as the source and it is not recognizing the parameter values.  Will that make a difference if the source is SSAS?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if the report works normally when you run it from Report Manager. Can you show me what kind of value you are passing as a parameter to SSAS? More specifically, can you show me the line of code you are using - parameters(x).Value = "xyz"...

Comment: Sure, here it is.  I've triple checked spelling etc. tried other parameter values but in the cmd line I'm getting the error "This report requeires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'LocTblBusinessOffice'.  To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a prameter value.

Comment: ' Prepare report parameter.
  Dim parameters(2) As ParameterValue
  parameters(0) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(0).Name = "LocTblBusinessOffice"
  parameters(0).Value = "AZ/NV CBO"
  parameters(1) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(1).Name = "LocTblFacility"
  parameters(1).Value = "381 ST JOHN'S PLEASANT VALLEY HOSP" 
  parameters(2) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(2).Name = "BAIPSPBAIPSP"
  parameters(2).Value = "PSP"

Comment: So those parameters are dimensions in the SSAS CUBE and when building the report I just checked the parameter box in the query.  That's different from how I would make parameters with a straight SQL source report if that makes any difference.

Comment: And more information, the LocTblBusinessOffice and LocTblFacility are from the same dimension (Loctbl) so when BusinessOffice is selected only those Facilities that are apart of that BusinessOffice appear in the drop down menu.

Comment: When you create parameters there is a label and a value. It looks like you are putting the label into your code. You need to put in the value - it will be in the unique name format for SSAS. I don't know your dimension but say something like [Hospital Group].[Hospital].[381 St John's Pleasant Valley Hosp]. That's what your parameter value needs to look like.

Comment: Awesome Stacia, thank you again, just needed the ampersand with the value so :[Hospital Group].[Hospital].&[381 St John's Pleasant Valley Hosp].   You've been so helpful so I hate to ask, and feel free to tell me to figure it out myself but I don't suppose you could add in the code for the looping?

Comment: Sorry to have to decline. I'm in the middle of a cross-country move of my business and household, and finishing the writing of a book. I really don't have time to help for several weeks. You just got lucky with the above code because I was working on something similar in a chapter around the same time as your request. :) Good luck - you're on the right path. The hardest part is knowing how to get your parameters set and the output produced.